# retrieve array index based on pushing elements into the array very simple

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to retrieve a value from an array where i pushed the elements in. i need to access the data using the index.

i did this:

```
var imgs=[];
imgs.push('fa/voaushfoadha.jpg');
imgs.push('fa/asfdgfsgfdgfdgf.jpg');
imgs.push('fa/dfsfssdfdfsfs.jpg');
imgs.push('fa/ghghghfghfhfg.jpg');
```

Now, I want to retrieve the element in position 2 (i need to use the position to access - `fa/asfdgfsgfdgfdgf.jpg`),

**how do i do this? i tried imgs[2] but that doesnt work**

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you getting an error after trying `imgs[2]`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It was construed incorrectly. I just wanted to know the notation of accessing indexes in arrays as that wasnt working but Its been resolved.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 3):

Arrays start their index on 0.  So to access the second element it would be `imgs[1]`.

```
imgs[0] => first item
imgs[1] => second item
...
imgs[i] => (i+1)th item
// you do the math
```

Comment: It was construed incorrectly. I just wanted to know the notation of accessing indexes in javasxcript  arrays as that wasnt working but Its been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

While arrays have a `length` property that starts counting from 1 (as non-programmers do), **array indexes are zero-based** -- that is, you start counting from zero.

To get the second element in an array, use index 1.

```js
var imgs=[];
imgs.push('fa/voaushfoadha.jpg');
imgs.push('fa/asfdgfsgfdgfdgf.jpg');
imgs.push('fa/dfsfssdfdfsfs.jpg');
imgs.push('fa/ghghghfghfhfg.jpg');

// The length property starts counting from 1:
console.log("The array has: " + imgs.length + " elements in it.");

// But indexes arezero-based. To get the second element, use index 1
console.log("The second element in the array is: " + imgs[1]);
```

Comment: It was construed incorrectly. I just wanted to know the notation of accessing indexes in javasxcript arrays as that wasnt working but Its been resolved.